# iPhone SDK UI element preview

Tags: iphone

Looking for some catalog/gallery(not UICatalog, just images), where I can see preview of each UI element in iPhone SDK, along with corresponding class name(eg datetime picker, calendar, the black switch bar on bottom). This will give me rough idea on which UI elements I can use in my app and go read about corresponding class.

Comment: Have you looked at interface builder? I might be wrong but I think thats what your looking for.

Comment: @thyrgle: sorry no Mac at the moment to check it, thought there could be a catalogue.

Comment: Well, basically on the drag and drop place you can look all the various UI elements and the various properties by just clicking on them. Its not really intended to be a catalog but you can use it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would *highly* recommend reading the [iPhone Human Interface Guidelines Document](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig). It's produced by Apple, and has a ton of great advice on how to craft interfaces as well as descriptions and guides for the standard UI elements.

You can also check out the [UIKit Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/uikit_framework/index.html), and the [wiki at CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?UIKit). If you need images, teehan+lax have a great [PSD template for mockups](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2009/06/18/iphone-gui-psd-30/)